# Core data error : File remains undeleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I execute a fetch request and i'm eventually getting the managed object . The managed object gets deleted on using `[managedObj deleteObject:file]` which    does not appear in further fetch request . But file remains in the memory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following `[managedObj deleteObject:file]` to delete the managed object .

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error]` to delete the file from internal memory.

Comment: Your answer does not follow from the question that you asked. You should have mentioned that you needed to remove a file, not just a managed object.

Comment: I've explained the same in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `[managedObj deleteObject:file]` deletes object from context not from memory. Try `[managedObj save:&error]` after `deleteObject` step.

Comment: I tried saving the context. `[context save:&error]; if (error) {NSLog(@"An error occurred while deleting a row: %@", error); }` . It doesn't help .

Comment: Refer this apple developer link. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/creating.html

Comment: Even after saving the context as in Apple Doc , file exists . Just the row gets deleted in `.sqlite` file.

Comment: What do you mean "file exists"? Do you mean the managed object still exists, or is there an actual file somewhere that you want to delete?